# Mybatis with JPA in SpringBoot

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm trying to use [JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) (@CrudRepository), but I want to create also my custom controller with Mybatis.

I have that working, but the problem is that for example in procedures, they don't work together.

Is it possible to implement JPA with Mybatis to work together?

I've been reading a lot, I understand that Mybatis is not ORM. Some blogs indicate that it's possible, but not how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to manage the both JPA and mybatis together under Spring Transaction. Both of them, in fact, can be rollback together within the same transaction. However, do take note of side effects such as:

e.g.

Within the same transaction:

```
// Perform insert and expect id to be returned 
TableA tableA = new TableA();
jpaRepositoryForTableA.save( tableA );

// Use the tableA in the next mybatis mapper
TableB tableB = new TableB();
tableB.setTableAId( tableA.getId() );

this.mapper.saveTableB( tableB )
```

In the scenario above, TableB will not be able to get the TableA's ID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's good idea at all. Use one or the other.

I can imagine that you could make it working, but your can't use them on top of same tables or use transaction management for both persistence frameworks.

So if you have such use case (you didn't explain any), I would argue that your application should be split into two separate services. Optionally consider to separate your storage into two separate DB instances.

Comment: I want to use them together for transactions. An use case can be for example the bank account transaction. I want to make all the transaction with Mybatis except the CRUD that it's supposed to be done with JPA :/

Comment: You didn't outline your use case, so I would argue that in most cases you should strive to avoid that. If you really can't I'm afraid you will need to use Distributed Transactions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction). But that will kill your performance.